# matplotlib animation not updating the plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

I've create a plot that contains a number of circle patches. I wanted to animate the plot, shifting the colors of the circles with each frame. My animation function is being called, and, in the debugger, I can see the circle patch's color changing, but, after each update, the image has not changed, showing the circle colors that were established originally.

```
def update(frames, ap, dc):
    print('update, frames=',frames)
    circles = ap.getAllCircles()
    iCircle = 0
    for patch in dc.ax.get_children():
        if isinstance(patch, patches.Circle):
            circle = circles[iCircle]
            colorIndex =  (circle.getGeneration()+frames)%len(facecolors)
            color = facecolors[colorIndex]
            #print(f'{frames=} {iCircle=} {colorIndex=} {color=} {circle.getGeneration()=}')
            patch.set_facecolor(color)
            iCircle += 1
            if iCircle >= len(circles):
                break
    
def main():
   create the circles...
   initialize the plot...
   for each circle:
      create a patch for the circle
      add the patch to the axes

    ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, interval=100, fargs=(ap, dc), blit=False, repeat=True)

    plt.show()
```

I'm wondering whether what I'm seeing (the plot image) is actually just the static plot I'd get if I weren't trying to animate it. The examples of animating I've looked at, however, implement it the same way.

Comment: I tried that. It didn't work. Besides, documentation states that if blitting is not used, the return value, if any, is ignored.

Comment: If I try to recreate your code on my system (windows with PyCharm), assign `ani` to a global variable, and call `FuncAnimation(..., frames=1)` the animation seems to work without problems. Perhaps you can try to explicitly call `dc.ax.figure.canvas.draw()` at the end of `update()`. Anyway, this strongly depends on the environment and backend you are using.